# Preserve proportion of graphs using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to arrange multiple plots using `grid.arrange`.
It does the job by the book, and when calling:

```
p1 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl = 4), aes(wt, mpg, colour = cyl)) + geom_point() 
p2 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl = 8), aes(wt, mpg, colour = cyl)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

I get two nice plots, symmetrical in size:

[image]

My graphs refer to different parameters but they do share the same colour coding for groups. So I'd like to remove the legend from all but one and find a nice place for it.

However when I try:

```
p3 <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl = 8), aes(wt, mpg, colour = cyl)) + geom_point() + guides(colour=FALSE)

grid.arrange(p3, p2, ncol = 2)
```

The plot without the legend gets (correctly) bigger:

[image]

I'd like to keep the size (as a length of x axis) to stay the same across graphs.

I'm aware I could use faceting here, but I'll also need to combine various graphs that (I think) will be hard to implement using facets..

Is it possible to do it with `grid.arrange`? Any other solutions that could help here?

Comment: you can accomplish this without `grid.arrange` by facetting. But there's no `class` column in `mtcars` for me to show that.

Comment: @Arun SOrry - my mistake. Switched example to cylinders. As I mentioned, I'm aware of the magic of faceting, however I'd like to get away without using it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this, which uses `cbind.gtable`:

```
grid.draw(cbind(ggplotGrob(p3), ggplotGrob(p2), size="last"))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I have about 20 lines of code I was just about to paste to accomplish the same thing with a bit of manual fiddling. I *wish* I'd known about `cbind.gtable` before now. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Thank you. Great solution indeed. But (same as Simon, I need to ask about aspect ratio - is it possible to preserve?

Comment: @SimonO101 -- Good question. Doesn't look like it provides for that. If one of you wants to pursue this, I might suggest looking at `getAnywhere("cbind_gtable")`, which is where the units appear to get set, and where you might want to modify the code.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien in that case I might just paste my answer which allows for controlling aspect ratios, but it's a lot more hassle than this!

Comment: @SimonO101 -- Cool. I thought of asking you to do that, and am glad you will.

Comment: what about I have different number of elements on x axis? I'e get back error: Error: nrow(x) == nrow(y) is not TRUE. But I still want to have the same size of my objects. do you have any ides? thank you !

Answer (score 12):

Not nearly as elegantly simple as @Josh 's solution, but you can do this with grid.arrange which allows you to preserve or specify the aspect ratio of the plots, but you need to make a `tableGrob` for your legend. I answered a simillar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16298599/1478381) which is where I got the handy code for making a tableGrob from a ggplot2 legend:

```
## Make a tableGrob of your legend
tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]

# Plot objects using widths and height and respect to fix aspect ratios
# We make a grid layout with 3 columns, one each for the plots and one for the legend
grid.newpage()
pushViewport( viewport( layout = grid.layout( 1 , 3 , widths = unit( c( 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.2 ) , "npc" ) ,heights = unit( c( 0.45 , 0.45 , 0.45 ) , "npc" ) , respect = matrix(rep(1,3),1) ) ) ) 
print( p1 + theme(legend.position="none") , vp = viewport( layout.pos.row = 1 , layout.pos.col = 1 ) )
print( p2 + theme(legend.position="none") , vp = viewport( layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2 ) )
upViewport(0)
vp3 <- viewport( width = unit(0.2,"npc") , x = 0.9 , y = 0.5)
pushViewport(vp3)
grid.draw( legend )
popViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although longer solution it does the job. Two (novice) questions: 1) Do the units of width sum to 1? What is the `respect` argument specifying?

Comment: I find the respsect argument a bit confusing, but essentially I consider it a matrix of the aspect ratio for each viewport, so we have `1,1,1` because we have 1 row and 3 columns and we want a 1:1 aspect ratio in each. That might not be *quite* how it works, but it helps me!!! The units of width don't *have* to sum to 1. You could squeeze them in in less than the width of the plotting region. "npc" is from 0 to 1, with 0 the left edge or bottom of the plot region and 1 the right edge or top and 0.5 the centre. Scale accordingly.]

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd update this thread because `grid.arrange` now has this functionality:

```
grid.arrange(p3, p2, ncol = 2, widths = c(1,1.2))
```

[image: equally sized panels]

Comment: Thanks! How did you arrive at `width` values? Is that approximate?

Comment: I estimated the relative proportions until it looked right.