# using ggsave and arrangeGrob after updating gridExtra to 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

since I read a lot similar question on stackoverflow so far, I couldn't find a good solution without updating ggplot2 to the development version.

My problem, I have several scripts which use `arrangeGrob` to create combined graph out of individual graphs. I save them into a variable and `print` this variable and/or save it with `ggsave`. Since a lot of my colleagues update there packages regularly (which is a good thing I think), I always get mails my script no longer work after updating to `gridExtra 2.0.0`.

I am not sure how to handle this, since the new `ggplot2` version where the problem is solved is still under development. I found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406991/saving-a-graph-with-ggsave-after-using-ggplot-build-and-ggplot-gtable) on stack overflow to remove a test if the object to save is a `ggplot` since the new `arrangeGrob` function returns a `gtable` object, but this fails in my case:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),
                y=c(2,3,4))
p <- ggplot(a, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
b <- arrangeGrob(p, p)
grid.draw(b)
ggsave('test.pdf', b)
ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave
body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]
ggsave('test.pdf', b)
```

Some output and error on the console:

```
d> grid.draw(b)
d> ggsave('test.pdf', b)
Error in ggsave("test.pdf", b) : plot should be a ggplot2 plot
d> ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave
d> body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]
d> ggsave('test.pdf', b)
Saving 10.5 x 10.7 in image
TableGrob (2 x 1) "arrange": 2 grobs
  z     cells    name           grob
1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
2 2 (2-2,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
d>
```

The `test.pdf` is created but it is corrupted in any way and can not be opened. Also the `gtable` object get printed. So I guess something is wrong here.

But, as you can see, I found in the example code, I found the `grid.draw` function to plot at least my combined graph but I still can not `ggsave` it after the modification.

I don't want to use the "old" (`pdf(file = "test.pdf");  grid.draw(b); dev.off()`) device saving functions as suggested in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134163/saving-plots-using-grid-draw-method-instead-of-gridextra), since they are very uncomfortable to use.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458051/store-arrangegrob-to-object-does-not-create-printable-object) someone asked exactly how to save the object, but in the answer they just explain to use `grid.darw` and he accepted the answer as `solving the problem` and nobody answered on my comments so far.

So I am pretty lost at the moment, how to provide working scripts for those who have and have not updated to new `gridExtra` package. The way to remove the test within the `ggsave` function is I guess the best solution since I can check the `gridExtra` and `ggplot2` version and just overwrite the `ggsave` function in case there version do not match, but I could not get it to run.

Looking forward to get some help.

**EDIT:**

maybe the `sessionInfo` helps

```
d> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_2.0.0 ggplot2_1.0.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-44      plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2    
 [6] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     stringi_1.0-1    reshape2_1.4.1   devtools_1.9.1  
[11] proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.0      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
[16] memoise_0.2.1
```

Comment: Did you try to use pdf() instead of ggsave? Something like that:  pdf(file = "test.pdf"); grid.newpage() ;print(b) ;dev.off()

Comment: This link may help: http://alstatr.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/r-how-to-layout-and-design-infographic.html

Comment: @YCR this is what I mentioned with the second link. I know this is working but is very unhandy. I would love to get the `ggsave` function working as suggested in the first link, because otherwise I have to change a lot of lines in my scripts...

Comment: I probably don't understand, but where is the error/problem with `ggsave` using your example?

Comment: @Pascal I added the output and a comment directly below, forgot to mention what the problem was :-)

Comment: It seems to work for me. A plot is saved in `test.pdf` using your example (`ggplot2` version `1.0.1.9003` and `gridExtra` version `2.0.0`).

Comment: @Pascal the `ggplot2 1.0.1.9003` is the development version which is also not easily to install for all users since the have to use `devtools` and download from github. So I would like to stay with stable versions but also use `ggsave` and not the `pdf()` and `dev.off()` functions as I all mentioned in my post.

Comment: Your example fails with `ggplot2` version `1.0.1`. But it works with the development version of `ggplot2`, version `1.0.1.9003`.

Comment: `grid.arrange` doesn't work ?

Comment: `grid.arrange` is directly plotting. But I want to save the object without plotting or plotting it later in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal brought me finally to the idea to check for the differences between `ggplot 1.0.1` and `ggplot 1.0.1.9003`, since I don't want to or force the development version of `ggplot`.

So my idea is a function which will be executed within each script which overwrites the default `ggsave` function.

I tested it now a little, if there are any bugs or so, please let me know. But the way I do it now it works so far.

```
repairGgsave <- function() {
  ggplot_version <- 
    compareVersion(as.character(packageVersion('ggplot2')), 
                 '1.0.1.9003')
  gridextra_version <- 
    compareVersion(as.character(packageVersion('gridExtra')), 
                   '0.9.1')
  if(gridextra_version > 0) {
    if(ggplot_version <= 0) {
      ggsave <- function(filename, plot = last_plot(),
                         device = NULL, path = NULL, scale = 1,
                         width = NA, height = NA, units = c("in", "cm", "mm"),
                         dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE, ...) {

        dev <- plot_dev(device, filename, dpi = dpi)
        dim <- plot_dim(c(width, height), scale = scale, units = units,
                        limitsize = limitsize)

        if (!is.null(path)) {
          filename <- file.path(path, filename)
        }
        dev(file = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...)
        on.exit(utils::capture.output(grDevices::dev.off()))
        grid.draw(plot)

        invisible()
      }
      assign("ggsave", ggsave, .GlobalEnv)
      plot_dim <<- function(dim = c(NA, NA), scale = 1, units = c("in", "cm", "mm"),
                           limitsize = TRUE) {

        units <- match.arg(units)
        to_inches <- function(x) x / c(`in` = 1, cm = 2.54, mm = 2.54 * 10)[units]
        from_inches <- function(x) x * c(`in` = 1, cm = 2.54, mm = 2.54 * 10)[units]

        dim <- to_inches(dim) * scale

        if (any(is.na(dim))) {
          if (length(grDevices::dev.list()) == 0) {
            default_dim <- c(7, 7)
          } else {
            default_dim <- dev.size() * scale
          }
          dim[is.na(dim)] <- default_dim[is.na(dim)]
          dim_f <- prettyNum(from_inches(dim), digits = 3)

          message("Saving ", dim_f[1], " x ", dim_f[2], " ", units, " image")
        }

        if (limitsize && any(dim >= 50)) {
          stop("Dimensions exceed 50 inches (height and width are specified in '",
               units, "' not pixels). If you're sure you a plot that big, use ",
               "`limitsize = FALSE`.", call. = FALSE)
        }

        dim
      }

      plot_dev <<- function(device, filename, dpi = 300) {
        if (is.function(device))
          return(device)

        eps <- function(...) {
          grDevices::postscript(..., onefile = FALSE, horizontal = FALSE,
                                paper = "special")
        }
        devices <- list(
          eps =  eps,
          ps =   eps,
          tex =  function(...) grDevices::pictex(...),
          pdf =  function(..., version = "1.4") grDevices::pdf(..., version = version),
          svg =  function(...) grDevices::svg(...),
          emf =  function(...) grDevices::win.metafile(...),
          wmf =  function(...) grDevices::win.metafile(...),
          png =  function(...) grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in"),
          jpg =  function(...) grDevices::jpeg(..., res = dpi, units = "in"),
          jpeg = function(...) grDevices::jpeg(..., res = dpi, units = "in"),
          bmp =  function(...) grDevices::bmp(..., res = dpi, units = "in"),
          tiff = function(...) grDevices::tiff(..., res = dpi, units = "in")
        )

        if (is.null(device)) {
          device <- tolower(tools::file_ext(filename))
        }

        if (!is.character(device) || length(device) != 1) {
          stop("`device` must be NULL, a string or a function.", call. = FALSE)
        }

        dev <<- devices[[device]]
        if (is.null(dev)) {
          stop("Unknown graphics device '", device, "'", call. = FALSE)
        }
        dev
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It basically overwrites the `ggsave` and creates two new functions from the development version.

After executing the function everything seems to work.

Comment: This seems relevant to me. Just one question: how should I apply it? Wrap around some ggsave-action? `repairGgsave(ggsave(paste0(PLOT_loc,"/",Today,"_ObsCoxQuint_CVD.eps"), 
       plot = multiplot(ObsQuintPlot_CVD + guides(colour = FALSE), 
                        CoxQuintPlot_CVD + guides(colour = FALSE), cols = 2), 
       width = 12, height = 12))`

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan I actually never got it to work in a solid way. To be honest, I never really checked babtists solution above. I implemented the solution with `grid.new();grid.draw()` in my scripts. Thought it might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

As an temporary workaround for this unfortunate transition period, you could re-implement the class hack that used to be in gridExtra,

```
class(b) <- c("arrange","ggplot", class(b))
print.arrange <- function(x) grid.draw(x)
ggsave('test.pdf', b)
```

Comment: This `arrange` workaround has to be applied on plot I create with `arrangeGrob`. Is there anything against the solution I suggested? In my case I only overwrite the `ggsave` function in case the versions of `gridExtra` and `ggplot`  are not compatible.

Comment: it's good to have different options, I wouldn't say one is better in this case. Personally I prefer not to duplicate large chunks of code for temporary workarounds because it tends to confuse my future self, but everyone has a different workflow and/or capacity to remember the past.

Comment: I just realised, if I use my function it no longer works for normal ggplot plots. It says `no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('gg', 'ggplot')"` I wonder how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me was explicitly defining the file:

`ggsave(file='test.pdf', b)`