# Proportion of legend to plot changes when printing two ggplots aligned with grid.arrange to one page (.pdf)

Tags: r, pdf, gridview, plot, ggplot2

I have a common legend for two ggplot2 graphs which are aligned with `grid.arrange()` (see code below). However, the legend does not adjust according to graph size, when I export graphs as one pdf.

For a comparison, here is the output of the individual plot:[image]

And after using grid.arrange with the following code:

```
pdf("Fig1.pdf", onefile=TRUE, paper="a4",width=3.22, height=5) 
grid.arrange(Fig1A,Fig1B)
dev.off()
```

I get this: [image]

The commands for the legend of plot A are:

```
    gglpot2
    +theme(legend.key.size=unit(0.5,'lines'))
    +theme(legend.key.height=unit(0.25,"cm"))
    +theme(legend.key.height=unit(1,"line"))
    +theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10))
    +theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.8))
    +theme(legend.direction = "vertical")
    +guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
```

The commands for the legend of plot B are:

```
    +theme(legend.position="")
```

I tried to solve the issue, according to:

[Keep or set the ratio between text labels and size of plot in grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298599/keep-or-set-the-ratio-between-text-labels-and-size-of-plot-in-grid-arrange)

which didn’t help, as it is quite similar but not exactly my problem.

https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arranging-ggplot

Here I followed the suggestion:
 draw your plots

```
 plot1 <- ggplot(...) # this specifies your first plot
 plot2 <- ggplot(...) # this specifies your second plot
 plot3 <- ggplot(...) # this specifies your third plot
```

merge all three plots within one grid (and visualize this)

```
 grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, nrow=3) #arranges plots within grid
```

save

```
 g <- arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, plot3, nrow=3) #generates g
 ggsave(file="whatever.pdf", g) #saves g
```

but I ended up with the same result and worse, as I didn’t have the margins I’d like to have.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/15-questions-all-r-users-have-about-plots/

[Printing multiple ggplots into a single pdf, multiple plots per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234248/printing-multiple-ggplots-into-a-single-pdf-multiple-plots-per-page)

didn’t help either, as my problem is not placing the plots on one page, but the ratio of legend size to plot.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

in the meanwhile I found someone outside this community who was able to help me. The solution is quite simple:

Change the code to

```
theme(legend.key.size=unit(0.5,'lines'),
legend.key.height=unit(0.32,"cm"),
legend.text=element_text(size=10),
legend.position=c(0.85,0.8),
legend.direction = "vertical")
```

so basically I removed

`theme(legend.key.height=unit(1,"line"))`

and

`guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))`

changed

```
 theme(legend.key.height=unit(0.25,"cm"))
```

to

```
theme(legend.key.height=unit(0.32,"cm"))
```

and that did the job.

I hope this may be usueful for someone else, facing a similar problem.
Best regards!